# Proof that addition of subspaces of a vector space $V$ is associative

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, self-learning, associativity

I am studying the Linear Algebra Done Right book by Sheldon Axler and one of the exercises is to verify whether addition on the subspaces of a vector space $V$ is associative. The exact phrasing of the question is, "if $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$ are subspaces of (vector space) $V$, is:"

$(U_1 + U_2) + U_3 = U_1 + (U_2+U_3)$
where $U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ stands for the sum of the subspaces **not the union of subspaces** and is a subspace.

I wanted to check the validity of a proof that would go as follows:
Let $x \in U_1$, $y \in U_2$ and $z \in U_3$
All elements of $U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ can be written as $x+y+z$
All elements of $(U_1 + U_2) + U_3$ can be written as $(x+y)+z$
All elements of $U_1 + (U_2 + U_3)$ can be written as $x+(y+z)$

Since $U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ is a vectorspace, we have associativity therefore $x+y+z$ = $(x+y)+z$ = $x+(y+z)$ showing that $U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = (U_1 + U_2) + U_3 = U_1 + (U_2 + U_3)$

Please correct me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

You mentioned "All elements of $U_1+U_2+U_3$ can be written as $x+y+z$". This is not obvious in the context of this question (it is basically the result you want to prove). So you cannot just use a notation like $x+y+z$ without justifying it. In general, you can add three *things* (like $x+y+z$) without specifying the order only when you have associativity for addition otherwise the notation is ambiguous.

The addition of vectors from these subspaces is always (by closure of addition over $V$) in $V$ so you can use the associativity of addition in $V$ to your advantage.

Like you said, say $x \in U_1, y \in U_2, z \in U_3$. Now you have to show that a member of $U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ defined by $(x+y)+z$ is exactly the same member defined by $x + (y+z)$ and that this is true for all $x$, $y$ and $z$. This just needs use of associativity of addition in $V$.

Comment: Thank you! In the context of the book (which I am guessing is not universal and therefore the confusion) U1+U2 is a sum of subspaces not a union. As in U1+U2 contains all the possible sums of elements from U1 and U2 and it is a subspace. I will amend the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'll fix the union symbols in my answer but the logic remains the same. The order of addition doesn't matter because all members of the subspaces are vectors of $V$ in which we always have associativity.

Comment: Regarding the x+y+z part, if my understanding is correct, it is the definition of sum of subspaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Sum . Granted, I might be missing something :)

Comment: That's exactly correct but I think it's also what you have to prove for the case where you have 3 subspaces. Am I understanding your comment correctly?

Comment: Yes I think you are understanding my comment correctly but the thing I want to prove is simpler that what you think. I can take for given that `U1 + U2 + U3` is a sum of subspaces and I just have to prove the (U1 + U2) + U3 = U1 + (U2 + U3)